# OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space

Tags: r, xlconnect, openxls

I'm using `XLConnect` with Java on a 64 bit platform. Even after adding

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g")
```

I'm unable to load a 22MB file with extension `.xlsx` in R.

Some people have suggested openxlsx package but as far as I know, it makes use of rJava as well.

Comment: physical memory at your machine? `sessionInfo()` as well?

Comment: openxlsx doesn't use rJava. It uses Rcpp instead.
You can see there: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf